# Numeric order by varchar

Tags: sql, t-sql, numeric, alphanumeric, sql-order-by

Hey guys I'm trying to sort my varchar column . I am almost done with it but I can't find the solution to make the following:

-999, -998, 0, 8A, 80, 80A, 90, A80, ADBA

At the moment it is (see code):
-998, -999, 0, 8A, 80, 80A, 90, A80, ADBA

I only need to fix the negative values. Anyone got a solution for this problem?

```
 SELECT RANK_NUMBER FROM SHIPMENT_EVENT
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(RANK_NUMBER) = 1 THEN RIGHT('0000000000' + RANK_NUMBER, 10) ELSE CASE 
                 WHEN LEFT(RANK_NUMBER, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN RIGHT( 
                 '0000000000' 
                     + LEFT(SUBSTRING(RANK_NUMBER, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', RANK_NUMBER 
                 ), 80 
                 ), 
                 PATINDEX 
                 ('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(RANK_NUMBER, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', 
                 RANK_NUMBER), 
                 80 
                 ) + 'X') -1), 10) 
                 ELSE RANK_NUMBER 
               END 
           END
```

Comment: Why is 8A less than 80 in the ordering? It almost looks like hex ordering, but that is not consistent. Can you explain the logic of ordering those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect something like:

```
order by cast(left(col, patindex('%[^-0-9]%', col + 'x') - 1) as decimal(20, 0))
```

Comment: If I do that, the negative values are fixed but the A80 and ADA values are converted to 0's. (-999, -998, 0, A80, ADBA, 8A, 80, 80A, 90) and it needs to be(-999, -998, 0, 8A, 80, 80A, 90, A80, ADBA)

Comment: I changed it to:

SELECT RANK_NUMBER FROM SHIPMENT_EVENT
ORDER BY CASE WHEN cast(NULLIF(left(RANK_NUMBER, patindex('%[^-0-9]%', RANK_NUMBER + 'x') - 1), '') as int) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, cast(NULLIF(left(RANK_NUMBER, patindex('%[^-0-9]%', RANK_NUMBER + 'x') - 1), '') as int)

And it worked, thanks!